# How to use data given back in an array in Angular 5

Tags: arrays, json, angular, rest, get

My backend is giving me an array of text:

```
['JamIt','JamItLite']
```

Here is my GET Request to get either version JamIt or JamItLite:

```
getVersion() {
    const url = this.JamItUrl + this.versionExt + 'Jamit/version';
    console.log(this.environment.getConfig('Url'));
    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('lanId', this.authService.username)
        .set('domain', 'NAM');
    const options = {
        params: params,
        responseType: 'text'as 'text' // Getting back text not JSON.
    };
    return this.http.get(url, options);
}
```

This is how I am rerouting the user in order to enter to either JamIt or JamItLite once the form is submitted:

```
onFormSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    if (this.signInForm.valid) {
      this.authService.username = this.signInForm.value.username;
      this.authService.password = this.signInForm.value.password;
      this.authService.loginUser().subscribe(
        response => {
          this.authService.isAuthenticated = true;
          this.authService.storeToken(response['access_token'], response['refresh_token']);
          this.daq.getVersion().subscribe(
            version =>  {
              this.authService.data = version;
              console.log(version);
              if (version === 'JamIt') { // checks if user has jam, it access, backend returned text not string, see daq service.
                this.router.navigate(['/jamit']);
              } else if (version === 'JamItLite') {
                this.router.navigate(['/jamitlite']);  // checks if user has jam it lite access, backend returned text not string, see jam service.
              } else if (version === 'JamIt' || 'JamItLite') {
                this.router.navigate(['/jamit']);  // checks if user has jam it and jamit lite, backend returned text not string, see jam service.
              }
              this.onLoginError(this.groupLoginErrorMessage);

            }
          );
        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.onLoginError(this.invalidCredentialsMessage); // wrong password for auth
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

How can I use what the backend is providing (the array of text mentioned earlier) in the front end to redirect the user to the correct application?

Comment: so this result = ['JamIt','JamItLite'] is return i this line: .subscribe(
            version =>  {
              this.authService.data = version;
              console.log(version); is that right?

Comment: yes! @SergeyRudenko